# How to update price of crypto currencies from binance in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have issue with updating price from BinanceAPI. I am using Xamarin.

```xml
<ScrollView HeightRequest="300">
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Symbol}" FontSize="24" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="24" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button Text="Click me" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Code C#:

```cs
ObservableCollection<InForOfCrypto> myList = new ObservableCollection<InForOfCrypto>();
string url = "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/cjdowner/cryptocurrency/256/Ethereum-icon.png";
    
List<PRICE> listOfPrice = CallPriceAPIFromBinnces();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    myList.Add(new InForOfCrypto()
    {
        Image = url, 
        Symbol = listOfPrice[i].symbol, 
        Price = listOfPrice[i].price
    });
}
    
listView.ItemsSource = myList;
```

I call Binance api it will return list of price of pair crypto all 5s it will auto call to api.

And now I only want to update to price field in list and other fields still maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _price;

    public string Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    } 

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
   {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
 }
```

And then reset the price value to update.

Or you could update the price value in list and then reset the itemsource.